# Can't resolve '@stripe/stripe-js'

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working in a react group project. My teammates implemented the payment system with stripe. Now after pulling code, I accepted the incoming changes and installed the packages then pushed to my repo. After starting the react project its showing me this error. I can not understand what went wrong. Any insights? Thanks in advance.
[image: error details]

Comment: did you installed the packages using `npm install @stripe/stripe-js` or `yarn add @stripe/stripe-js` ?

Comment: I only used the npm i as the package-lock.json was updated

Comment: oh the problem was that automatically installed the react stripe whereas they used the only stripe package. thanks movila